# Why there are SELinux errors in permissive mode?

Tags: selinux, centos8

I have set CentOS 8 Stream with SELinux set to `permissive` but I still have bunch of red lines in the log e.g.:

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/lib/systemd/systemd from name_connect access on the tcp_socket port 80
```

Are these real or its just printing - what would be happening if it was in `restrictive` mode?

Comment: Disabling or setting `SELinux` to `permissive` mode is not recommended. It is there for a reason. A better approach would be to look into the problem and solve it with `SELinux` enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the documentation:

> When SELinux is running in permissive mode, SELinux policy is not
> enforced. The system remains operational and SELinux does not deny any
> operations but only logs AVC messages, which can be then used for
> troubleshooting, debugging, and SELinux policy improvements.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/using_selinux/changing-selinux-states-and-modes_using-selinux

Also see `/etc/selinux/config`

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#       enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#       permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#       disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=permissive
```

Comment: yes this is why I asked because these bits of log are printed as if they were errors not warnings and I dont really know were these actions stopped or let through with the print in the log.. they could have made it more clear in the log text

Comment: Even in Permissive mode, SELinux is blocking/denying file access. I am directly experiencing this in CentOS8 and RL8 as are others: https://github.com/jellyfin/jellyfin/issues/8114